# W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: invoke type does not match method type of

Tags: java, android

I've encountered this error quite frequently... especially when accessing private methods of a class... Really have no clue what this is about... Neither can I find much explanation from Google..

I just post an example that cause the exception here:

I have a SyncAdapter, here is the onPerformSync method that caused the crash..

```
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
                              ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        // some code...

        HmacSHA224 mac = new HmacSHA224(accessToken.getBytes());
        JSONArray entries = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray hashes = null;
        String lastName = null;

        // some other code
    }
```

HmacSHA224 is a custom class I defined as below:

```
public class HmacSHA224 {

private SHA224 mMessageDigest;
private byte[] mKey;

public HmacSHA224(byte[] key) {
    mMessageDigest = new SHA224();
    mKey = key;
}

public byte[] hash(byte[] message) {
    int blockSize = 64;
    int digestSize = 28;
    if (mKey.length > blockSize) {
        mKey = mMessageDigest.digest(mKey);
    }

    if (mKey.length < blockSize) {
        byte[] k = new byte[blockSize];
        System.arraycopy(mKey, 0, k, 0, mKey.length);
        mKey = k;
    }

    byte[] o = new byte[blockSize + digestSize];
    byte[] i = new byte[blockSize + message.length];
    for (int n = 0; n < blockSize; n++) {
        o[n] = (byte)(mKey[n] ^ 0x5c);
        i[n] = (byte)(mKey[n] ^ 0x36);
    }

    System.arraycopy(message, 0, i, blockSize, message.length);
    System.arraycopy(mMessageDigest.digest(i), 0, o, blockSize, digestSize);

    return mMessageDigest.digest(o);
}
```

}

And SHA224 class:

```
public final class SHA224 extends MessageDigestSpi {

    private static int[] H = { some values };

    private static int[] K = { some values };

    private ByteBuffer dataBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(64);
    private int length = 0;
    private int[] h = H.clone();

    private void processChunk() {
        dataBuf.rewind();
        int[] w = new int[64];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            w[i] = dataBuf.getInt();
        dataBuf.clear();

        for (int i = 16; i < 64; i++) {
            int s0 = w[i - 15];
            s0 = ((s0 >>> 7) | (s0 << 25)) ^ ((s0 >>> 18) | (s0 << 14)) ^ (s0 >>> 3);
            int s1 = w[i - 2];
            s1 = ((s1 >>> 17) | (s1 << 15)) ^ ((s1 >>> 19) | (s1 << 13)) ^ (s1 >>> 10);
            w[i] = w[i - 16] + s0 + w[i - 7] + s1;
        }

        int a = this.h[0], b = this.h[1], c = this.h[2], d = this.h[3],
                e = this.h[4], f = this.h[5], g = this.h[6], h = this.h[7];

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            int s0 = ((a >>> 2) | (a << 30)) ^ ((a >>> 13) | (a << 19)) ^ ((a >>> 22) | (a << 10));
            int maj = (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c);
            int t2 = s0 + maj;
            int s1 = ((e >>> 6) | (e << 26)) ^ ((e >>> 11) | (e << 21)) ^ ((e >>> 25) | (e << 7));
            int ch = (e & f) ^ ((~e) & g);
            int t1 = h + s1 + ch + K[i] + w[i];

            h = g;
            g = f;
            f = e;
            e = d + t1;
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = t1 + t2;
        }

        this.h[0] += a;
        this.h[1] += b;
        this.h[2] += c;
        this.h[3] += d;
        this.h[4] += e;
        this.h[5] += f;
        this.h[6] += g;
        this.h[7] += h;
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] engineDigest() {
        long bitLength = length * 8L;
        engineUpdate((byte) 0x80);
        for (; (length + 8) % 64 != 0;)
            engineUpdate((byte) 0);
        dataBuf.putLong(bitLength);
        processChunk();

        ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(28);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            result.putInt(h[i]);

        engineReset();
        return result.array();
    }

    @Override
    protected void engineReset() {
        dataBuf.clear();
        length = 0;
        h = H.clone();
    }

    @Override
    protected void engineUpdate(byte src) {
        dataBuf.put(src);
        length += 1;
        if (length % 64 == 0)
            processChunk();
    }

    @Override
    protected void engineUpdate(byte[] src, int offset, int count) {
        for (int i = offset; i < offset + count; i++)
            engineUpdate(src[i]);
    }

    public byte[] digest(byte[] input) {
        engineUpdate(input, 0, input.length);
        return engineDigest();
    }

}
```

I found the crash happens when I initiated the mac value.. the error trace into

> VFY:  rejected Lim/com/example/utils/SHA224;.engineDigest ()

UPDATE:

I had the following logs:

```
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: invoke type does not match method type of Lcom/example/android/utils/SHA224;.processChunk
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6f at 0x002b
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/android/utils/SHA224;.engineDigest ()[B
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/dalvikvm﹕ Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/android/utils/SHA224;
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415daba8)
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/System.err﹕ java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/android/utils/SHA224
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/System.err﹕ at com.example.android.utils.HmacSHA224.<init>(HmacSHA224.java:5)
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/System.err﹕ at com.example.android.adapters.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:71)
09-03 14:38:59.841  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync W/System.err﹕ at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
09-03 14:38:59.851  25084-25134/com.example.android:sync E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
    Process: com.example.android:sync, PID: 25084
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/android/utils/SHA224
            at com.example.android.utils.HmacSHA224.<init>(HmacSHA224.java:5)
            at com.example.android.adapters.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:71)
            at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
```

UPDATE AGAIN
so the problem lies in processChunk() method, when changed to protected (instead of private) the crash disappeared. BUT!!! I want to know why it behaves so.. Why can't I keep some methods private and calling within the same class...

Comment: Could you post a bit more info on the error you are seeing, (copy-paste of the stacktrace would be good), and the constructor of your `SHA224` class ?
Have you encountered this yourself on a given device or only saw it in remotely aggregated logs (like Google Play console) ?

Comment: @desseim please take a look at the logs added. SHA224 is from Android, not my code. I encountered this on device not remotely. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no `SHA224` class in the Android API and if you look at the stack message you'll see it's in package `com.example.android.utils` which is the same package as your `HmacSHA224` class.
I believe there is something wrong with the initialization of the `SHA224` class instances.

Comment: @desseim you're right.. I'm such an idiot lol. Posting the SHA224 code

Comment: @desseim FYI, if I changed processChunk() to protected, it would work. basically, whenever there's a calling of private methods, I would face the problem. But I don't want to change all the methods to protected/public. that's not the right way to do.. I want to know what the heck is going on :(

Comment: The logs are telling you that the `SHA224` class bytecode verification failed while trying to load it in the VM. If I understand it correctly, it tells you that the bytecode which corresponds to the call to `processChunk()` in the `engineDigest()` method is trying to call the implementation of `processChunk()` in the parent class, which doesn't exist. Why the compiler doesn't see `SHA224#processChunk()` unless it is `protected` I have no idea yet. I tried to copy-paste your code in a dummy gradle project and it worked fine.Are you sure nothing is different in your project?Which SDK do you use?

Comment: I would suggest you put details of your build and run environments in your question (build tools version, target API, Android version it is executed on...), and try to build it targeting API19 and run it on some Android 4.4 or similar (pre-L) environment to check.

Answer (score 1):

Not a definite answer on why this happens yet, but here's my analysis of what's happening and directions to investigate:

What the logs say is that the bytecode verification of the class `SHA224`, while trying to load it in VM memory, failed:

```
Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/android/utils/SHA224;
```

The details tell us that the verification failed because of a call to the parent class implementation of `processChunk()`, which doesn't exist in the `MessageDigestSpi` parent class:

```
VFY: invoke type does not match method type of Lcom/example/android/utils/SHA224;.processChunk
  VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6f at 0x002b
  VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/android/utils/SHA224;.engineDigest ()[B
```

(opcode `0x6F` is for calling super method [on Dalvik](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html))

So it looks like the call to `processChunk()` in your code is compiled to `super.processChunk()`, which naturally fails to resolve at load time. Why, I can't say, it may be a bug in the build tool chain, especially since you say just changing the `processChunk()` method scope to `protected` compiles it correctly.

Further things to try for investigation:

- try calling `this.processChunk()` instead of `processChunk()` (which should be the same but would hint at a compiler issue)
- try compiling against a stable API version (e.g. 19) with the latest build tools, and run it on a stable Android runtime (e.g. 4.4)

I tried your code on my environment (SDK tools 23.0.2, platform-tools 20, target min. API 8, run on 4.4 / Dalvik) and I didn't encounter this problem, even with the digest code put in a sync-adapter running in a separate process.
So I would definitely give a check at your building environment.

---

This won't solve the root of the problem, but for hashing on Android you could rather use the [native API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html):

```
MessageDigest sha224 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-224");
// etc
```

It will fail on device which don't provide SHA-224 hashing algorithm though...

Comment: wow!!! Respect! I couldn't get time to further investigate earlier. Upvote your suggestion for now and would try what your suggested and get back to you tomorrow!! Highly appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was in `buildToolsVersion` set to 19 and `compileSdkVersion` set to 21 in `build.gradle`. So my advice is, try to change your `buildToolsVersion` to as high number as possible.